# How to get information from two database tables at once? (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I want to show top rated articles on one of my website pages, but there is an issue.

I have all article text, author, date, time etc. in one table called **stories**,
and I have vote results in another table called **votes**.

The problem is that, when I get article info from database I need to order it by votes that correspond with it (in votes table I have vote value and id of article that it corresponds to).

So how can I display articles from **stories** table, but order it by vote value from **votes** table that corresponds to the article?

Pseudo code of this could be:

```
SELECT * FROM stories ORDER BY //Votes from votes table where article_id corresponds to this article
```

Comment: you should get basic understanding of how SQL works and what relational algebra is to successfully work with SQL databases. Try to read some books on your free time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't see your table structure, but assuming your relationship is `stories.article_id = votes.article_id` this is a very simple `JOIN` with an `ORDER BY`.  You should review basic SQL `JOIN` syntax, as this is sort of a SQL 101 question. If your article identifier column in `votes` is different than `votes.article_id`, substitute it below.

```
SELECT
  stories.*,
  votes.votes
FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.article_id = votes.article_id
ORDER BY votes.votes DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a field such as vote_story_id corresponding to story_id use this :

```
SELECT stories.*, vote.vote_number FROM stories, votes WHERE vote_story_id = story_id ORDER BY vote.vote_number DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you?

```
SELECT stories.* FROM stories JOIN votes on votes.article_id = stories.id WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably storing one row for each vote, so you can track which user made the vote. In that case, you can do:

```
select s.*, vc.Count
from Stories s
left outer join (
    select StoryID, count(*) as Count
    from Votes
    group by StoryID
) vc on s.StoryID = vc.StoryID
order by vc.Count desc
```